# Git : How to change repo's owner name?

Tags: github

I'm currently working on my last semester git project, and my teammate is the one who created the initial repo on git.

He then sent me an invitation to join the repo as a collaborator.

Currently it shows like this in my repo space:

[image: Screen]

Where SomeUserName is my teammate name.

I want to change this, so that it shows my username instead in my own page, how should i do it?

Comment: You can't. Unless you are an Admin. See https://help.github.com/articles/renaming-a-repository/

Comment: Thanks, I will be updating this topic as soon as I'll get the admin privileges. I thought that the simple fact that I could push to the master branch made me one. Also this link seems to explain how to rename the whole repo, which is slightly different than only renaming the "username" owning it.

Comment: Quick update : So after discussing with my teammate and a glimse at google results, i found out that it may be impossible for a non-organization account to give admin privileges for it's collaborators. I'm still continuing the investigation.